# Why Can't I Upgrade from 9.2.3 to 9.2.4 Using Composer?

Tags: composer

If I check for outdated artifacts using:

```
composer outdated "drupal/*"
```

I can see Core needs updating:

```
drupal/core                       9.2.3             9.2.4
drupal/core-composer-scaffold     9.2.3             9.2.4
drupal/core-dev                   9.1.5             9.2.4
drupal/core-recommended           9.2.3             9.2.4
```

...

However, when I try to update:

```
composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies
```

I get the following messages:

```
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly allowed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package rector/rector-prefixed is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use rector/rector instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
```

This site was original built in Drupal 8, but has been upgraded to Drupal 9.

Any suggestions on how I might fix this issue?

My composer.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/recommended-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "drupal/address": "^1.9",
        "drupal/advagg": "4.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/asset_injector": "2.x-dev",
        "drupal/charts": "^5.0@alpha",
        "drupal/coffee": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/composer_deploy": "^1.6",
        "drupal/config_views": "^2.0",
        "drupal/core": "9.2.3 as 8.9.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1.5",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.1.5",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1.5",
        "drupal/devel_entity_updates": "^3.0",
        "drupal/domain": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/domain_site_settings": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.5",
        "drupal/drupalmoduleupgrader": "^1.7",
        "drupal/dynamic_asset": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/email_registration": "^1.1",
        "drupal/exclude_node_title": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/feeds": "3.x-dev",
        "drupal/feeds_tamper": "^2.0",
        "drupal/field_css": "^2.0@RC",
        "drupal/field_formatter_class": "^1.5",
        "drupal/filefield_paths": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/formblock": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/geocoder": "^3.17",
        "drupal/geophp": "^1.0",
        "drupal/group": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/gtranslate": "^1.13",
        "drupal/image_effects": "^3.1",
        "drupal/jquery_ui": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/jquery_ui_sortable": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/leaflet": "^2.1",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0@beta",
        "drupal/masquerade": "2.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/media_directories": "^2.0",
        "drupal/media_library_form_element": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/media_migration": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/menu_twig": "^1.4",
        "drupal/migrate_plus": "^5.1",
        "drupal/migrate_process_inline_images": "^1.0",
        "drupal/migrate_source_csv": "3.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/migrate_tools": "5.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/ng_lightbox": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/office_hours": "^1.3",
        "drupal/optimizedb": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.12",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
        "drupal/php": "^1.1",
        "drupal/prepopulate": "^2.3",
        "drupal/quiz": "6.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.6",
        "drupal/search404": "^2.0",
        "drupal/shortcode": "2.0.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/sitemap": "^2.0@beta",
        "drupal/theme_switcher": "^1.1",
        "drupal/ultimate_cron": "^2.0@alpha",
        "drupal/upgrade_rector": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/video": "^1.5@alpha",
        "drupal/video_embed_field": "2.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/views_data_export": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/views_slideshow": "^4.8",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.0@alpha",
        "drupal/webform_migrate": "1.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/weight": "^3.2",
        "drupal/xhprof": "^1.0@beta",
        "drush/drush": "^10.4",
        "geocoder-php/google-maps-provider": "^4.6",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.81",
        "webmozart/assert": "^1.10"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "web/core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "web/libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^9.1.5",
        "kint-php/kint": "^3.3",
        "mglaman/drupal-check": "^1.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.4.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, try composer remove --dev drupal/core-dev. And composer update drupal/core-recommended:^9.2. maybe conflict by core-dev.

Comment: I have just tried composer remove --dev drupal/core-dev. And composer update drupal/core-recommended:^9.2. Still getting "Nothing to install or update". Anyway, thanks for the suggestion Mr D.

Comment: The drupal.org documentation - https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer - says to use `composer update drupal/core "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies`. Does it help?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what needs to be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have some really dirty hacks in your composer.json. A line like `"drupal/core": "9.2.3 as 8.9.0"` is a very bad idea and is always going to explode sooner or later. The intention usually is to upgrade Drupal core v9 while keeping v8-only/v9-incompatible modules, but trying to do something like this is just plain wrong.

1. Remove all lines `drupal/core***` except `drupal/core-recommended` and `drupal/core-composer-scaffold`. Those two will require all other stuff, the superfluent `drupal/core***` just make future upgrading harder.
2. In your other post there is the error message `...drupal/theme_switcher 1.1.0 requires drupal/core ^8.5...`. This module is incompatible with Drupal v9 (and maybe has been the cause for the very bad idea mentioned in earlier). Luckily there is now a `drupal/theme_switcher:^1.2` which is compatible with Drupal v9.
3. In my experience the most reliable way to update Drupal core is to explicitly require a new minimum version of core-recommended and core-composer-scaffold: `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^9.2.4 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9.2.4 --update-with-dependencies`.
4. In your special case you also need to update the v8 Theme switcher module to get a full set of v9 compatible packages: `composer require drupal/core-recommended:^9.2.4 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9.2.4 drupal/theme_switcher:^1.2 --update-with-dependencies`

Comment: Unfortunately `"drupal/core": "9.2.3 as 8.9.0"` and friends is kind of sanctioned: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-to-drupal-9-or-later. They give it as an option and only call it _less recommended_ rather than giving its proper title of _avoid at all costs_

Comment: Thanks @Hudri. I've tried these steps, but am currently getting msg: - drupal/core-recommended 9.2.4 requires drupal/core 9.2.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[9.2.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Conclusion: remove drupal/core 9.2.3

Comment: @BrettS try to include drupal/core:^9.2.4 in the "composer require", and "composer remove" if afterwards

Comment: Turns out one of my problems was several contrib modules that were locally patched for Drupal 9. These modules  but were still only downloadable as Drupal 8. In spite of the fact that the info files stated "^8 || ^9" composer was throwing errors. So, I removed references to those modules from composer files and then I was able to run `composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^9.2.4' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^9.2.4' --update-with-dependencies`. Thanks @Hudri

Answer (score -1):

You've locked `drupal/core-recommended` to version `9.1.5` in this line:

```
"drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1.5",
```

I believe you can fix this by running:

```
composer update drupal/core-recommended:^9.2. -W
```

Edit: Also, this doesn't look good to me, but I don't think it has anything to do with your problem:

```
    "drupal/core": "9.2.3 as 8.9.0",
```

I'm guessing someone did some aliasing for upgrade purposes or something. I think I'd try removing the `as 8.9.0` from that.

Comment: NB! The caret notation "^9.1.5" doesn't lock the version - read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md - it just blocks upgrading to Drupal 10.

Comment: No, it's a locks it to the regex you've provided which states 'the version starting with the string 9.1.5', which essentially locks it to version `9.1.5`, since no other versions will start with this unless the `9.1` branch got to `9.1.50` and so on.

Comment: @Jaypan No, this is incorrect, the `^` has nothing to do with regex at all, it is a major version lock, as @hansfn mentioned. The rule you are describing is the tilde `~` version range. `^9.1.5` means `>= 9.1.5 and < 10` while `~9.1.5` means `>=9.1.5 and < 9.2`

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: This could use better documentation, because you can get different results between ^9.0 vs ^9.2, same for modules, depending on dependency calculation. I just experienced this with a contributed module and was hard to spot because of the minor version causing it.